# Is it possible to have both internal and external fragmentation together?

Tags: memory-management, memory-fragmentation

As I know it, internal fragmentation applies only to fixed size blocks and external fragmentation applies only to dynamic sized blocks.

Is it technically correct to call this situation(obviously has internal fragmentation) external fragmentation?

```
---
Block1 (empty)
---
Block2 (half full) (internal fragmentation)
---
Block 3 (empty)
---
```

Say, a process P can't fit in block1 or block2. But it can fit in their sum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's entirely possible to have both together. In a typical case, you have a limited number of block sizes, such as rounding each allocation to the next larger power of 2.

That limits the number of different sizes of blocks, so an existing free block is more likely to satisfy a particular allocation request, but still leaves a number of different block sizes, so external fragmentation is possible. At the same time, it means the requested size and the block size won't necessarily be identical, so you'll also often have some internal fragmentation.